# mysql - count query a query result

Tags: mysql

I have one table; cars

cars has many fields: color, make, model, crashed, etc etc

I query the table:

select all from cars where color is red

I then want to query that result, to count how many have crashed.
(crashed field being a boolean)

so in the end, the data i should have is all the fields of the red cars, and to know that x have crashed

Is it possible to do this with only one knock at the mysql door?
or do you have to do two seperate queries?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual queries instead of query pseudo code. What have you tried to combine both into one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some data:

```
mysql> select * from cars;
+-----+-------+---------+
| SNO | color | crashed |
+-----+-------+---------+
|   1 | red   |       0 |
|   2 | red   |       1 |
|   3 | red   |       1 |
|   4 | blue  |       1 |
|   5 | blue  |       1 |
|   6 | blue  |       1 |
|   7 | blue  |       0 |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

and a query:

```
mysql> select color,sum(crashed),count(*) as total from cars group by color;
+-------+--------------+-------+
| color | sum(crashed) | total |
+-------+--------------+-------+
| blue  |            3 |     4 |
| red   |            2 |     3 |
+-------+--------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes thats it! -> sum - thats what i was looking for! thanks

Comment: now my next question is, can i use SUM to count strings, so if it says 'crashed' in the field to count it as 1, and if empty to count as 0? thanks

Comment: perhaps: `select color,sum(if(crashed_s='crashed',1,0)),count(*) as total from cars group by color;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE color = "red" AND crashed = TRUE
```

Or whatever your crashed indicator is, I've only worked with SQL a bit, but I believe
this query will show all cars of red color and have a crashed value of true.

Comment: no, see this just gives me the data of red, crashed cars - i want all the data of the red cars, both crashed and non-crashed, and also to know how many have crashed

Comment: This revised query might work: `SELECT *, SUM (CASE crashed WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM cars WHERE color = "red" GROUP BY crashed`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use a `WHERE` clause.

`SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Color = 'red' AND Crashed = true`

Or if you wanted crashes by color,

`SELECT color, count(*) FROM Cars WHERE crashed = true GROUP BY color;`

Or, as you clarified, `SELECT crashed, count(*) as yourval FROM Cars WHERE color = 'Red' GROUP BY crashed`

Comment: no, sorry, this just gives me the data of red, crashed cars - i want all the data of the red cars, both crashed and non-crashed, and also to know how many have crashed

Comment: @lan if you are aggregating a count, you can't also have all the data. I added another query for you to try if you like